# prevent copy and paste in url using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to prevent user from browsing web page by copying and pasting the URL in same browser or another browser in jquery
i tried this code but it is not working.

```
$('input[type=text],textarea').bind('copy paste cut drag drop', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: what you want to accomplish?

Comment: Please elaborate on your question. Do you have some kind of kiosk and want to disallow pasting in a field or disallow pasting in the location bar?

Comment: i have a form, this form opens automatically when user press the form name. i want to prevent user to copy this form url and paste in another tab or browser to disallow him to open the same form twice in the same time, need to make this url read only and prevent user from copy and paste or hide this form url.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the form in new window using javascript, so that location / address bar will not be visible. And so it can not be copied.

```
window.open('your url here','winname','directories=no,titlebar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=400,height=350');
```

Hope this helps...